# Association on LINQ on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, associations

[image][image][image]

I have a GUI that is connected to Instrument.  When I select an instrument type in GUI, I want the corresponding instrument id from "InstType" table(Instrument type...).  Then store it into a variable called __InstrumentType.

I need the variable __InstrumentType to return the InstType's ID.

```
MyDataModelContainer FItype2 = new MyDataModelContainer();  //new instance of the entity container

            //retrieves a string type data from GUI's combobox
            string _InstrumentType = this.comboBox_InstType.GetItemText(comboBox_InstType.SelectedItem);
            //create a variable 
            int __InstrumentType=0;

        var list = (from IT in FItype2.InstType1
                    where IT.TypeName == _InstrumentType
                    select IT.Id).Last();
```

Comment: Do you want to get `ID` of the `InstType` by its `TypeName`?

Comment: What does "*I am not getting the corresponding InstType's ID*" mean??? Do you get another ID or do you get an exception (and which exception)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will update the original question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a list you shouldn't use Single - it returns only one element (throws exception when collection contains more). Try this:

```
var list = (from IT in FItype2.InstType1
                    where IT.TypeName == _InstrumentType
                    select IT.Id).ToList();
```

In your question you've marked that you are interested in InstType Ids.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  It started working when I changed

```
var list = (from IT in FItype2.InstType1
            where IT.TypeName == _InstrumentType
            select IT.Id).Last();
```

to

```
var list = (from IT in FItype2.InstType1
            where IT.TypeName == _InstrumentType
            select IT.Id).Max();
```

LINQ is still in the early stage.  It won't give you detailed feed back on errors (or don't even catch when there is an error).